# My app stops unexpectedly and force closes

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to develop a simple calculator using only 1 `EditText` box. There are no errors but it does not run. Whenever a press any button my app stops unexpectedly. I have tried everything. I have used the same code and made a calculator using 3 `EditText` boxes and it works fine. I can't understand what is the error.

```
    package com.example.cal;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;



    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText text1 ;
    Button add,subtract,mul,div,result;


    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    add=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    subtract=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    subtract.setOnClickListener(this);
    mul=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mul.setOnClickListener(this);
    div=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    div.setOnClickListener(this);
    result=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    result.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    float c=0;

    public void onClick(View view) {


      float inputValue1 = Float.parseFloat(text1.getText().toString());
      float inputValue2;
        switch(view.getId())
        {

        case R.id.button1:

             Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             inputValue1 =inputValue1+ Float.parseFloat(text1.getText().toString());


        case R.id.button2:
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            text1.setText("");
            inputValue2 = Float.parseFloat(text1.getText().toString());
            c=inputValue1-inputValue2;
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
             Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             text1.setText("");
             inputValue2 = Float.parseFloat(text1.getText().toString());
             c=inputValue1*inputValue2;
             break;

        case R.id.button4:
             Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             text1.setText("");
             inputValue2 = Float.parseFloat(text1.getText().toString());
             c=inputValue1/inputValue2;
             break;
          }

        if(view.getId()==R.id.button5)
        {Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           text1.setText("result is: "+inputValue1);}
        }
}
```

And here my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"  >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/add" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/subtract" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/mul" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/div" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/result" />
```

Comment: You should add the error shown in the Android log to see why and where it stops

Comment: maybe somebody turns it off?

Comment: Check to make sure the logcat isn't filtered. If your using eclipse I have seen it sometimes stop receiving logcat. If this happens you can either kill the adb server running ``adb kill-server`` followed by ``adb devices`` which will restart and show that the device is reconnected. Or if this doesn't work close eclipse and the emulator and start again. If your app is force closing there will always be an error in the log cat

Comment: Also, may not be the reason but your first case statement hasn't got a break statement so it will drop through into the next case. I don't know for certain but the crash might be caused by the Toast. Instead of using view.getContext() use ``ActivityClassName`` so for you it would be ``MainActivity`` instead

Comment: Wait, how do you have a calculator with only 5 buttons?

Comment: After setting the text1 to "", you are trying to parse it to a float ?? Also if your logcat in eclipse is not working use the commandline: adb logcat -d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's working fine u can try dis

```
package com.example.testandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText text1 ;
Button add,subtract,mul,div,result;
float inputValue1 ;
float inputValue2;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

add=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
add.setOnClickListener(this);
subtract=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
subtract.setOnClickListener(this);
mul=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
mul.setOnClickListener(this);
div=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
div.setOnClickListener(this);
result=  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
result.setOnClickListener(this);
}
float c=0;

public void onClick(View view) {

try{
    Log.d("Input data ", Float.valueOf(text1.getText().toString()).toString());
    inputValue1 = Float.valueOf(text1.getText().toString());

    switch(view.getId())
    {

    case R.id.button1:

        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        inputValue1 =inputValue1+ Float.valueOf(text1.getText().toString());


    case R.id.button2:
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        inputValue2 = Float.valueOf(text1.getText().toString());
        c=inputValue1-inputValue2;
        break;

    case R.id.button3:
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        inputValue2 = Float.valueOf(text1.getText().toString());
        c=inputValue1*inputValue2;
        break;

    case R.id.button4:
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        inputValue2 = Float.valueOf(text1.getText().toString());
        c=inputValue1/inputValue2;
        break;
    }

    if(view.getId()==R.id.button5)
    {Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    text1.setText("result is: "+inputValue1);}
}catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. now it is running. i"ll be really grateful if u could help me further. now everthng is fine but everytime the result is displayed 0 only. plzz help!!!!

Comment: okk i accept ur answer but plzz do help me further. i am a beginner and cant understand why i am getting result 0 always

Comment: plzzzz see my code n tell why i always getting the result as 0.

Comment: put log on the calculation u will be doing some mathematical mistake

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when there is empty string in the edit text
try using

```
 try{

 //onclick code
}

catch( NumberFormatException ex ) {

   Log.d("Exception",":"+ex.getMessage());
}
```

And another thing is that you are setting the edit text to empty and fetching its value onclick

```
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ext1.setText("");
                inputValue2 = Float.parseFloat(text1.getText().toString());
                c=inputValue1-inputValue2;
```

Instead set to empty after fetching the value from edittext

```
  Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  inputValue2 = Float.parseFloat(text1.getText().toString());
  c=inputValue1-inputValue2;
  text1.setText("");
```